# Word 2010 repeating section content control

Tags: ms-word, word-2010, word-2013

Is there a library/plug-in/add-in for Word 2010 to support the repeating section content control like the one in Word 2013?

Another question, how can I programmatically convert the Word 2013 (with repeating section content control) so that it can be viewed properly in Word 2010?

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Joanna, did you ever receive an answer to this question?  I'm in the same bind here, we've implemented 2013 but a lot of users are still on 2010.